# Objective C draw in view dynamically

Tags: objective-c, xcode, draw

I have seen many examples of views being subclassed to override drawRect, but that approach is pretty static (at least as far as I understand).

What I'd like to do is set up a very simple drawing canvas. In that, I've got a view with a UIPanGestureRecognizer attached to it. Whenever the gesture fires a new position, I'd like to draw a circle of a fixed size and color in that position of the view. The gesture recognizer is attached to the view, but it fires a selector in the view controller. I already have a subclass of a UIView. So, what would be the best approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do in this case is still to override `drawRect`!

The difference is that you, when recognising gestures, need to keep track of the location(s) in which this circle should be drawn, and access that information the next time you are redrawing the view, essentially building up an image in memory that you draw into the view.

Comment: So I need to save every event and redraw it all from scratch in drawRect? That's more or less exactly the thing I was hoping I wouldn't have to do…

Comment: Or do I need to redraw the new stuff, and it at least saves that stuff that has previously been drawn?

Comment: You could also keep an image on hand, and edit that as you go along, in which case you wouldn't have to save events or redraw from scratch.